# Rust - Why does dereferencing and borrowing break borrowing rules?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

As per my understanding, there can be multiple immutable references at a time but if there is a mutable reference it can be the only *usable* reference.

Why does the following code work?:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut y = String::from("bar");

    let f: &mut String = &mut y;
    let f2: &String = &(*f);

    // not allowed since mutable reference already exists
    // let f3: &String = &y; 

    println!("{}, ", f.as_str());
    println!("{}", f2.as_str());
}
```

Edit: Another part of my question which I guess isn't obvious is: why am I not allowed to create `f3` (like I am doing in the commented line) when it is exactly the same thing as `f2` and created similarly by refrencing `y`.

Comment: Not related exactly to this question, but _"if there is a mutable reference it can be the only reference_" is not exactly correct. What you mean to say, I think, is "if there is a mutable reference it can be the only _usable_ reference."

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler is smart enough to know if the data actually is used as mutable before it is used as immutable. If you change the code at all to use the mutable reference first, it fails.

```
fn main() {
    let mut y = String::from("bar");

    let f: &mut String = &mut y;
    let f2: &String = &(*f);
    f.clear();

    // not allowed since mutable reference already exists
    // let f3: &String = &y; 

    println!("{}, ", f.as_str());
    println!("{}", f2.as_str());
}
```

Here's a link to a live [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09a7172475b587166356384aa02ad748). The error, as you'd expect, mentions you cannot have an immutable reference if a mutable one exists.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*f` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
5  |     let f2: &String = &(*f);
   |                       ----- immutable borrow occurs here
6  |     f.clear();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
12 |     println!("{}", f2.as_str());
   |                    ----------- immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

In short, you can only have one borrow if you have a mutable reference, but the compiler is intelligent enough to know when the value cannot change: in your example, `f` cannot change when it is used before `f2` is used, so it knows it doesn't change.

Comment: I don't think the compiler has to rearrange anything, I think the reason why this works is because the compiler figures out that `f.as_str()` only requires an immutable reference. So even though `f` is a mutable reference, nothing after the `let f` line requires mutable access to `y`.

Comment: @cdhowie I misread the order of the original borrows, but yeah, that is correct. Basically, the compiler knows there is no mutable borrow required.

Comment: But then why does it prevent the creation of ‘f3’? Which is the same thing as f2.

Comment: @user3690467 Good question. I guess because the order matters? I guess it's smart enough to deal with `f2`, but not smart enough for `f3`. It has to understand one additional borrowing depth at `f3`, and I guess it can't do that. With `f3`, you first borrow mutably from `y` and then immutably from `y` again. With `f2`, you first borrow mutably from `y` and then immutably from the mutable borrow. So in `f2` you kind of have a linear chain, while in `f3` you have kind of a forking.